# Laravel get nested relation value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is exist a possibility to easy get relation value in Laravel 5?
Here an example of what i need:

I have model `Book` and i have `author` relation to model `Author`. `Author` also have relation `country` to model `Country`. I need to show on book page country name of Author. I can easy wrote:

```
echo $model->author->country->name
```

But what if a author of book not provided or we don't know author coutry? I will got a notice.

So I need to add additional checkings:

```
if ($model->author && $model->author->country) echo $model->author->country->name
```

Maybe exists some method in laravel, which simplify getting a value?
Maybe something like `SomeHelperClass::getValue($model, 'author.country.name')`, so if some part of the chain is `null`, then method also returns `null`. Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you add a method $Book->countryName() to the Book were it checks the author if exist return the country name if not return null or empty string. In other words: Wrap the logic of retrieving the country name in that method

Comment: @DavidLavieri because i have a lot of similar situations and wrap each checking into separate method isn't wise desicion.

Comment: SomeHelperClass::getValue($model, 'author.country.name') would be as well wrappers and checking or actually queries to database behind the covers, probably even more messy since laravel abstractions are so... abstracts

Comment: @DavidLavieri you can check my answer and use the solution in future. Cheers.

Comment: there is more complexity behind it. But I guess is fine if operation and time complexity is not a matter for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question. Anyway:

Laravel 5.1 has helper function `array_get`, which works similar to what i want. But problem is that function works only with arrays. So i need to eager load all required data and convert object to an array:

```
$model = Book::with('author.country')->findOrFail($id);
$country_name = array_get($model->toArray(), 'author.country.name');
// or
$country_name = object_get($model, 'author.country.name');
```

Comment: Then `object_get($model, 'nested.relation.field')` also will do

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages self answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer